# ELK with Kafka and Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, elastic-stack

I'm not expert about 'big data' :)

My scenario is a couple of EC2 instances than producing logs.

These logs are basically Syslog and application events ( custom logs ).

I would like to use an ELK stack to catch logs, apply filters and show data.

In some cases, I would like to send my custom events to a dedicated queue system ( rabbitMQ ) for processing data ( recommendation engine ).

My question is, why I should use tools like Kafka and Hadoop if basically, I want just parse the logs with 24h retention and move them with a log rotate function from Debian?

Thanks a lot for your help! and sorry for my bad English ^^

Comment: It doesnt sound like you need Kafka or Hadoop for the getting data into ELK part. There are plugins for Logstash to get data from syslog into ES.

Comment: I'm sorry, probably the question seems stupid but in all tutorials, I've seen they use Hadoop or Kafka in front of ELK stack.

Comment: You don't need Kafka for point to point integration but most people would use it to feed multiple downstream sinks and replace RabbitMQ with it at the same time for feeding the recommendation engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If somebody is interested I've solved in this way:

1 - Instead to use the default log rotate I've chosen to use a Cloud Watch service, basically It takes logs from the EC2 and store them in a cloud.

2 - For push data to Logstash I've used the Lambda service, basically it is an environment where you can execute  Java, Javascript ( Nodejs ), or Python code. It takes the streaming data flow from CloudWatch, I've chosen to store the logs on S3 through a small Nodejs script.

3 - The Logstash instance consume logs directly from S3, there is a plugin input for that purpose.